# Как получить имя пользователя вошедшего на сайт?

Tags: php

Изучаю PHP. Есть список заданий.Строим систему авторизации на нашем сайте:

Строим систему авторизации на нашем сайте:

1. Для начала создайте несколько полезных функций и выделите их в отдельный файл:

   1. Функция getUsersList() пусть возвращает массив всех пользователей и хэшей их паролей
   2. Функция existsUser($login) проверяет - существует ли пользователь с заданным логином?
   3. Функция сheckPassword($login, $password) пусть возвращает true тогда, когда существует пользователь с указанным логином и введенный им пароль прошел проверку
2. Добавьте функцию getCurrentUser() которая возвращает либо имя вошедшего на сайт пользователя, либо null
3. Добавьте к проекту страничку login.php, которая:

   1. ЕСЛИ пользователь уже вошел (см. пункт 2), ТО редирект на главную страницу
   2. ЕСЛИ пользователь не вошел - отображает форму входа
   3. ЕСЛИ введены данные в форму входа - проверяем их (см. пункт 1.3) и ЕСЛИ проверка прошла, ТО запоминаем информацию о вошедшем пользователе
4. Модифицируйте ваш проект: позволяйте загружать изображения в галерею только авторизованным пользователям, ведите лог (запись в файл) с данными: кто, когда и какое изображение загрузил

Нет полного понимания, как решить задачу №2 с текущим пользователем. Подскажите куда копать. Есть мысль, что нужно пометить пользователя с помощью cookie и потом сверять данные полученные от пользователя. Но как сверять? Как закрепить за пользователем определенную куку? Может, я ошибаюсь. Буду благодарен за советы. Код предыдущих заданий для полноты картины.
// возвращает список пользователей и хэш их паролей

```
function getUsersList(){
    return [
        'Ivan' => '$2y$10$XJtEqRpa6FZkYh8Iy3NL3OHAFAZKS4DI2HSNKuSDvoRtDKNo3gcF2', // 123
        'Igor' => '$2y$10$EERFSFh.FjTR8CN9y4Km8Ou0sV.ESaPRVIUJroeBdUnYXXoB/pm22', //1234
        'Katya' => '$2y$10$u0YjeCbNOGAtnGCEHtXnSOO8.1G4o7n.3O8gSy5bK92PmFBwP7rqS', //12345
        'Karl' => '$2y$10$Xd37KgZhU2eBeofD4kMneeDRVauQuCSUb0gGtg96yJ6l9fYgUi4AK', //54321
    ];
}

//проверяет - существует ли пользователь с заданным логином

function existsUser($login){
  return isset(getUsersList()[$login]);
}

// возвращает true тогда, когда существует пользователь с указанным логином и введенный им пароль прошел проверку

function checkPassword($login, $password){
   return (existsUser($login) && password_verify($password, getUsersList()[$login]));
}
```

Comment: я думаю, до кук здесь еще дело не дошло, и речь о проверке данных, введенных через форму.

Comment: Но ведь данные, которые прилетели через форму уже прошли проверку. Функция existsUser($login)проверяет есть ли пользователь в условной БД (массив) и функция checkPassword($login, $password) проверяет пользователя и введенный им пароль. Судя из названия функции в задании getCurrentUser() нужно вернуть имя текущего пользователя, то есть который уже прошел предыдущие проверки.

Comment: Ну тогда пиши в сессию

Comment: Да,да,да. НО как именно узнать, что это тот же пользователь? Мне в сессию нужно положить куку и то, что прилетело с формы (имя, хэш пароля и т.д.)? Для того, чтобы потом по прилетевшей вновь куке понять, что это тот же пользователь? Или это как-то по другому реализовывается?

Comment: в сессию класть имя пользователя после того как он прошел проверку пароля

Comment: А куку не нужно? Если пользователь сам удалит куку, то что будет служить идентификатором  текущего пользователя? Имя в сессии?

Comment: про куки вообще забудь

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Напиши здесь потом полученное решение в виде ответа.

Comment: Окей! Еще раз спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// возвращает либо имя вошедшего на сайт пользователя, либо null

function getCurrentUser(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){
        return $_SESSION['login'];
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это сокращается до `return $_SESSION['login'] ?? null`

Comment: Мне пока не известно об этой записи. Спасибо за подсказку.